# The right way to handle additional user data in Django?

Tags: django, oop

I need to attach a significant number of additional properties to every user in my Django project.  Some of these properties are simple CharFields, others are more complex ManyToManyFields.  The trouble for me, is that in my digging around of ways to do this, I've found two options: [The user profile method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) explained in the documentation, and the [user subclassing method](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) I see floating around the internet.

They both look complicated, and I'd rather not choose one only to find out that I need to go back and switch everything to the other method after months of development, so I ask here.  Which way is the *right* way?

Comment: I was fighting with this too. Profiles add an extra unwanted layer, and sub-classing creates an extra unneeded table in the DB (I believe), and doesn't work with `request.user` without some more modifications. This seems like such a common scenario, you'd think there would be a definitive and nice way to do this. Other frameworks follow a "cascading" over "overriding" paradigm where you  can extend all the base classes with ease, and just have them work, but no, that would be too convenient.

Comment: If you prefer User class to have all extra fields, you can have it to, but this requires some additional work, when syncing the database. You simply add fields in a certain model and alter the database table by hand. It ain't pretty, but there is not unwanted layer and table. You simply write:

User.division = ForeignKey('Division')

and then add proper column to the table. But I believe this would be masochism myself ;-) Subclassing is just fine, especially that ORM will hide two tables from you.

Comment: @gruszyczy: It is possible to simply monkeypatch additional fields onto existing models, as you say. But your code to do it is broken. You have to do this for the field to be reliably set up correctly: models.ForeignKey('Division').contribute_to_class(User, 'division')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always done it traditional way, which means user profile, because it was suggested in the docs, but this is not the very clearest and elegant solution. You must always handle the possibility of user not having a profile, which I don't like very much. In the next project I would like to use the subclassing and if only it is in stable version of Django, I will press co-workers in my company to try this. This seems much more natural.

If you want to stay safe, use proile. If you prefer to take a little risk and benefit from a much better solution, use subclassing. It was introduced for a reason - there were several talks about weaknesses of profile solution.

Comment: Not too many answers on this one, but this one, combined with the only other answer seem to be pointing me in the profile direction.  If it goes south, I'll be sure to pose a followup here ;-)

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended, and, it seems, easiest, is the user profile method.

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen a different path: I had a Clients model, witch should be authenticated. Instead of extending the user model to adjust to my Clients model, I left them separated. And then, when I save a new Client, in the Client save() method I create a user for that client. Then I do the same for updating and deleting to keep them in sync. I tried the other two options, but each had a lot of cons, that's why I gave up on them. And this has been working for me very well.

Regards. Aldo.

Answer (score 0):

Like aldux, I prefer to create a separated Model and let User model untouched.